# How can I change MySQL to MariaDb in LAMP installation

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I'm a new LAMP developer, and I need to change MySQL to MariaDB in installed Denwer package. So, please, tell me, what should I do for it? I need to reinstall MySQL only (how can I do it? just delete all files?) and install MariaDB or I need to do anything else?

Comment: This question seems answered in the [MariaDB FAQ](http://kb.askmonty.org/en/how-can-i-upgrade-from-mysql-to-mariadb/)

Answer (score 2):

As specified in the [FAQ on the MariaDB website linked.](https://kb.askmonty.org/en/how-can-i-upgrade-from-mysql-to-mariadb/) MariaDB and MySQL are fully compatible.  You can simply uninstall mySQL and install MariaDB and everything should work.  If you're not sure how you would go about uninstalling and reinstalling mysql then [superuser.com](http://superuser.com) is probably the place to start.