# How to replace MySql with MariaDb in WAMP?

Tags: php, database, wamp, mariadb

I have a [Wamp server](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) installed on Windows and it works perfectly. [This article](http://developers.slashdot.org/story/13/05/05/2050220/there-is-no-reason-at-all-to-use-mysql-mariadb-mysql-founder-michael-widenius) at the Slashdot inspired me to migrate from MySql to MariaDb and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11308533/how-can-i-change-mysql-to-mariadb-in-lamp-installation) states that I can uninstall mysql and install MariaDb and it will work fine. However on Windows "Uninstall programs" section at control panel doesn't list something like MySql, i have only WampServer 2.2. Consequently, how can i replace [MariDb](https://mariadb.org/) with MySql on Windows or do i have to install php, apache, mariadb seperately?

Comment: MySQL will still run as a separate windows service, you should be able to stop/disable the MySQL service and then install MariDb in parallel (only running one at any one time unless you run it on different port numbers to avoid conflicts)

Comment: if i do it, will phpmyadmin use mariadb or do i have to to some configuration?

Comment: Assuming your control user/pass are the same, I'm going to guess no configuration changes if MariDB is a 100% drop in replacement.

Comment: You can try Neard (similar to Wamp) which have MariaDB in his package : https://sourceforge.net/projects/neard/

Comment: Things like WAMP aren't terribly flexible. Lando or Vagrant may be a better choice.

Answer (score 2):

Theoretically, you can install mariaDB in parallel to WampServer's mySQL, but to put it to run, you will have to alter one of the DB's port, because they use the same connection port. That is a good solution, if WampServer doesn't "upgrade" to mariaDB in it's package.